# How should I implement these vectors in c++? It pertains to latitude and longitude with vectors

Tags: c++, loops, vector, struct

As I added the code, I cannot cout anything nor get anything to happen outside of what was already provided
here is part of my code so far

```
    // ADD CODE HERE TO:
    // 1) Add the start point to the path.
    path.push_back(startPt);
// 2) Add a new point to the path starting at 0 km (i.e., the start point) and then at every        50     km until
    //    the final destination. You can call the ComputeLatitudeAndLongitude() function to help   with this.
double initialdirection= direction, distancetravelled = 0;
while (distancetravelled <= distance)
{
    Coordinate a = ComputeLatitudeAndLongitude(startPt, initialdirection, distancetravelled);
   path.push_back(a);
   distancetravelled + 50;
}

       // 3) Add the end point to the path.
      path.push_back(endPt);
```

is there anything wrong with the way I wrote this? the objective is to compute the points on the path every 50km until the destination and then print a kml file to use in google earth, however the computer does not do this command. Am I using vector properly?

Answer (score 2):

Try `distanceTravelled += 50;`. You need to modify it for the loop to work.

Comment: Wow thanks, can't believe I totally missed that. But now the system is outputting the wrong latitudes and longitudes where it should have longitudes of 51 and I get like 0.8